# PHP function "if a second parameter is specified"

Tags: php, function

I've got a simple function to conditionally convert units into feet or inches for display. I'd also like to use it to conditionally add the actual text `ft` or `in` to the end. I can't just add that text in every case, because I'd end up with `36 in x 24 in x 10 in` when what you want is `36x24x10 in`.

So basically I'm trying to do this:

```
function ex($x, $y) {
    if only $x is specified {
        if ($x < 50) {
            return $x/25.4
        }
        else {
            return $x/304.8
        }
    }
    elseif $x and $y are both specified {
        if ($x < 50) {
            return ' in';
        }
        else {
            return ' ft';
        }
    }
}

echo ex($NumberToConvert).'x'.ex($OtherNumberToConvert).example($NumberIWantToConvert,1);
```

But of course that results in "missing argument 2" warnings. The obvious hack is to use `if ($y > 0)` and *always* have to specify two arguments (making the latter 0 when I'm looking for numerical output and 1 when I'm looking for text). But is there something more elegant?

(yes I know this only makes sense if both numbers are <50 or neither are)

Comment: `function ex($x, $y='') {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [**default argument values**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) of a funciton. So your `ex` function should be like this:

```
function ex($x = null, $y = null) {
    if($x != null && $y == null){
        if ($x < 50) {
            return $x/25.4
        }else{
            return $x/304.8
        }
    }elseif($x != null && $y != null){
        if ($x < 50) {
            return ' in';
        }else{
            return ' ft';
        }
    }
}
```

Take the default argument as `null` for both `$x` and `$y` in the function, and process these variables inside the function accordingly.